# I get no animation when I perform the segue programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a button that will segue to another View Controller. In `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` I check the identifier and returns `NO` for this certain button after calling my own method `nextClicked`.

In `nextClicked` I do a HTTP Request and check some stuff, and then if everything is OK I do

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"getstartednext" sender:self];
});
```

The problem is that I get no animation now... The segue is of type modal. If I return `YES` in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and don't to the segue programmatically later, the animation appears and everything is as it should.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as such, but: why don't you do your checks before the initial `performSegue` call, instead of basically intercepting the first segue, then firing it again?

Comment: I do check before performSegue in shouldPerformSegue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`. If you want to do something special in response to the button click, use action-target and *not* a segue connected to the button.

Comment: I figured. I wanted the segue because of the animation you get, and how easy it is to go back again :)

Comment: I tested to do a segue programmatically from another place in the code. Animation seems to work fine then...

Comment: Read what I said. I didn't say you can't have the segue programmatically. But you are mixing automatic with programmatic. Don't.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project with your idea and I've got animation.

This is the action connected through IB with the next `viewController` and with identifier:  `@"getstartednext"`

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{

}
```

Same code you have except sender is `nil`

```
- (void) nextClicked
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"getstartednext" sender:nil];
    });
}
```

`if` sender != nil, (`IBAction` `go:`) then I'm calling `nextClicked` because returning `NO`
`else` the code is doing the segue because returning `YES`

```
- (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"getstartednext"] && sender != nil)
    {
        [self nextClicked];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Works like a charm.